# How to match two patterns with a space between them in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know how to match one pattern using JavaScript:

```
var pattern = somePattern

    if (!pattern.test(email)) { //do something }
```

but what if I have to match  2 patterns with a space between them so if I have this:

```
word1 word2

word1 should match pattern1
word2 should match pattern2
a space should be between them
```

How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

`word1word2` is refused (even if they much `pattern1` and `pattern2` in order, because of the lack of space)

`word1` should be an IP; `word2` should be a number

Some examples:

```
172.30.10.10 10 (acceptable)
172.30.10.1010 (not acceptable)
10 10 (not acceptable)
10 172.30.10.10 (not acceptable)
```

Comment: Can't you have 1 combined pattern that includes the space?

Comment: An example would help

Comment: @kornieff,see Updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source

The RegExp object has a `source` property, which returns a string representation of the regex.

Here's an example.

```
var validName = /\w+ \w+/
var validEmail = /[^@ ]+@.+\..+/
var combined = new RegExp(validName.source + ' ' + validEmail.source);

console.log(combined.test('John Doe jdoe@example.com'));
// outputs true

console.log(combined.test('John Doe bademail@'));
// outputs false
```

However, keep in mind that this solution will NOT work if the regexes include boundary markers like `$` and `^`.

Comment: +1, was just about to post the same. Constructing a new pattern from the existing ones is absolutely the correct solution. Under normal circumstances, I would say that the line-delimiters (`$` at the end of the first or `^` at the beginning of the second) aren't a problem, since it doesn't make sense to have "a space between them" anyway, but since you're converting the pattern to a string, you could potentially strip the offending characters if need be. Also, this solution doesn't matter if the patterns are constructed with `/abc/`, `new RegExp("abc")`, or passed as parameters to a function.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

Combine it into a single pattern:

```
var pattern = /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\s+\d{1,}/;
var test= '172.30.10.10 10';
var matched = test.match(pattern);
```

http://regex101.com/r/kU9cN3/3

**UPDATE** further to Brian's comment. If they need to be coded as separate patterns you can do as follows. This may be useful if you want to re-use patterns or make other combinations.

```
var ip = /\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/,
    number = /\d{1,}/,
    combinedRegExp = new RegExp(ip.source+' '+number.source);
var testString = '172.30.10.10 10';
var result = combinedRegExp.test(testString);
console.log(result);//true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Lrsxov8/

Comment: @BrianS then this wouldn't be a suitable solution. but you could still have a combined pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Joe Frambach's answer, you could perform some sanity checking on the input:

```js
function combinePatterns(pattern1, pattern2, options) {
    if (pattern1.constructor != RegExp || pattern2.constructor != RegExp) {
        throw '`pattern1` and `pattern2` must be RegExp objects';
    }

    var pattern1_str = pattern1.source;
    var pattern2_str = pattern2.source;
    options = options || {};

    // Ensure combining the patterns makes something sensible
    var p1_endOfLine, p2_startOfLine;
    if (pattern1_str.lastIndexOf('$') == pattern1_str.length - 1) {
        p1_endOfLine = true;
        if (options.stripBadDelimiters || options.swapBadDelimiters) {
            pattern1_str = pattern1_str.substr(0, pattern1_str.length - 1);
        }

        if (options.swapBadDelimiters
            && pattern2_str.lastIndexOf('$') != pattern2_str.length - 1) {
            pattern2_str += '$';
        }
    }

    if (pattern2_str.indexOf('^') == 0) {
        p2_startOfLine = true;
        if (options.stripBadDelimiters || options.swapBadDelimiters) {
            pattern2_str = pattern2_str.substr(1);
        }

        if (options.swapBadDelimiters && pattern1_str.indexOf('^') != 0) {
            pattern1_str = '^' + pattern1_str;
        }
    }

    if (p1_endOfLine && p2_startOfLine && options.swapPatterns) {
        var tmp = pattern1_str;
        pattern1_str = pattern2_str;
        pattern2_str = tmp;
    }

    return new RegExp(pattern1_str + ' ' + pattern2_str);
}

var first = combinePatterns(/abc/, /123/);
var second = combinePatterns(/abc$/, /^123/);
var third = combinePatterns(/abc$/, /^123/, { stripBadDelimiters: true });
var fourth = combinePatterns(/abc$/, /^123/, { swapBadDelimiters: true });
var fifth = combinePatterns(/abc$/, /^123/, { swapPatterns: true });

// first = /abc 123/
// second = /abc$ ^123/
// third = /abc 123/
// fourth = /^abc 123$/
// fourth = /^123 abc$/
```

This isn't the end-all be-all of what you can do to help ensure your input produces the desired output, but it should illustrate the sorts of possibilities that are open to you when reconstructing the regex pattern in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more compact and complete solution:

```
var ipNum = "\\d{1,3}";
var ip    = "(" + ipNum + "\\.){3}" + ipNum;
var num   = "\\d+";

var ipRE  = new RegExp("^\\s*" + ip + "\\s+" + ipNum + "\\s*$");

console.log(ipRE.test(" 172.30.10.10   10   ")); // true
```